# Set data to ADO database via WCF Web Service

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, insert, ado.net

I'm trying to create an application where I can insert data into a database via a Web Service. I have a good connection to my ADO Database but when I try to send information from my main application to my Web Service I get the following error.

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'MathServiceReference.IMathService' in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching
>   this contract could be found in the client element.

My main app

```
protected void btnMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceReference1.MathServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.MathServiceClient();
    txtSvar.Text = client.Multiply(int.Parse(txtTal2.Text)).ToString();
}
```

My class in my Wwb Service

```
public int Multiply(int box2)
{
    if (box2 == null)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        koppling db = new koppling();
        var testet = new tests();
        testet.namn = box2.ToString();
        db.tests1.AddObject(testet);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return 2;
    }
}
```

My WCF configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Show you're WCF client configuration.

Comment: I have add it now to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your WCF configuration lacks endpoints, at least one, e.g.:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="MathService">
            <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" contract="MathServiceReference.IMathService" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: This also needs to be mirrored with an endpoint inside the `client` element in the consuming application. Should be created when you create the proxy, but if you add it now, and don't want to recreate the proxy, you can add it manually.

Comment: I added the endpoint above under system.serviceModel and i also get the same error, here is the end point in my applikation under the client

<client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:53197/MathService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMathService" contract="ServiceReference1.IMathService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IMathService" />
        </client>

Comment: @AliRiyadh: Please post resulting configuration for both server and client. Also have you add mex endpoint? This is a metadata endpoint allowing easier discovery so you can test your service by browser or test client (find WcfTestClient.exe under VS folder).

Comment: I have done some changes in the configration files, now i get this error when i write somthing "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: @AliRiyadh: Hard to say. Try to rollback and debug step by step. Also in what config's line exactly do you get the error?

Answer (score -1):

See the following code example:

```
var jokeService = new JokeOfTheDayServiceClient();
jokeService.GetJokeCompleted += (s,e) =< jokeService_GetJokeCompleted;

private void jokeService_GetJokeCompleted(object sender, GetJokeCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Cancelled)
    {
        jokeTextBlock.Text = e.Result;
    }
}
```

It seems your problem is you need to have a "Completed" function to be called when the client has completed communicating. If you try to access it straight away the network might not have finished communicating the information yet.

Comment: very funny, but not helpful